# Alternativa para File API para navegador ultrapassado

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

Preciso ler o binário de um arquivo e postar para uma determinada URL, mas sem armazenar o arquivo propriamente dito para o servidor (não posso armazenar o arquivo).

Para complicar - eu adoraria usar a API de arquivos do HTML5 para isso, mas tenho que suportar o IE9 (em todos os sentidos da palavra "suportar"), que não implementa HTML5.

Existe alguma forma? Seria possível, por exemplo, usar algum mecanismo de upload para interceptar o arquivo no momento em que está subindo, para então ler seu conteúdo e cancelar o upload via Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode armazenar o arquivo nem temporariamente?
Se sim, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

1) Você cria um ajax que faz o upload do arquivo para uma pasta /tmp (propositalmente para o arquivo ser apagado depois);

2) Esse ajax chama um método no seu servidor ( pode ser shell script ou php mesmo);

3) Esse método vai ler e retornar o binário que vc quer e apagar o arquivo;

4) Esse binário estará armazenado no seu objeto javascript (success), depois basta pegar o valor desse objeto e colocar na sua url.

Se precisar de ajuda para implementar esse passo a passo me avisa que eu edito a resposta e coloco um código exemplo.